# Screen HTML in User Input?

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a solution to screen html tags. Stack Overflow has some of the basic html allowed but I am looking for a solution for my website. I also need it to be in PHP.
I remember seeing something on google but I can't seem to find it after goggling a lot today.

Comment: Please post any code or specific ideas that you've come up with, and we'll be glad to to help

Comment: Very glad, indeed. Right? @bphillips201

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5512756/2536029

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is probably about to be closed. Here's why. ***Per the flagging menu***: _Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Consider reading the [help](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) section before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: +1 for giving an answer to a poorly asked question.

Comment: What @MohammadAreebSiddiqui said.