# Difference between Html purifier and Html sanitizer

Tags: php, html, security

I'm looking to sanitize third party Html to display on my website. [Html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and [Html sanitizer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3746-PHP-Remove-unsafe-tags-and-attributes-from-HTML-code.html) have been mentioned in other posts.

I am wondering what are the differences between the two, and which one should I use ?

On their website, Html purifier gets compared with other tools, but not with Html sanitizer.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512712/sanitizing-html-input

Comment: HTML Purifier is a long-standing project to *sanitize* string data. Your link to "Html sanitizer" appears to be a file someone authored for a tutorial (I'm not going to signup to view the file contents of  `sanitizer.class.php`). You should use HTML Purifier or htmLawed in practice.

Comment: You should also use a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to prevent anything running that may break out of the sanitizer in future.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for the swift answers guys, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks also for the link on Content Security Policy, that's really interesting

Comment: I didn't find how to or up vote your answers though

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Vic. It's because we've all posted as comments rather than "as an answer". :-)   If you want to reply, don't forget to use @username and then they'll get an inbox alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the comments here so you can mark as answer in case it it useful to others.

Credit to [@Jared Farrish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish):

> HTML Purifier is a long-standing project to sanitize string data. Your link to "Html sanitizer" appears to be a file someone authored for a tutorial (I'm not going to signup to view the file contents of `sanitizer.class.php`). You should use HTML Purifier or htmLawed in practice.

In addition, you You should also use a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to prevent anything running that may break out of the sanitizer in future.

Also, you may find the following post useful: [Escaping rich text editor output](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/49342/8340)