# HTML purifier not working with $_POST before inserting into mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, htmlpurifier

I have this [text editor](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/559/) on a wordpress blog and I want to use `HTML Purifier` to purify users' input before inserting into database. The text editor is an iframe so I get the content by using

```
   document.getElementById("comments_comments").value=$("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html();
```

when users click on the submit button.

I follow the basic instruction from html purifier like this:

```
  if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && $_SESSION["user"] != "") 
  {   
    require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $comments = $purifier->purify($_POST["comments"]);
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare ("INSERT INTO mytable SET comments = %s",array($comments));
    $wpdb->query($sql);
  }
```

But the code doesn't have any effect at all. I was expecting the `<script>` tags completely removed, but they are still stored in the database as & lt ;script & gt ; which I think is the work of the wpdb prepare statement. Does the above configuration not work with `$_POST`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to simply sanitize user input, htmlspecialchars() does just fine. If you want to remove all tags (which is only appropriate if you are format shifting from HTML to TXT) striptags() and then htmlspecialchars() will do just fine. HTML Purifier is overkill, anyway.

Comment: @Xabier, I want to keep the html tags though. Is there any other options?

Comment: i see.. then, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512712/sanitizing-html-input

Answer (score 0):

First make sure, you realy disallow this tag:

```
$config->set('HTML.ForbiddenElements', ['script']));
```

You talking about ending with this in the database:

```
& lt ;script & gt ;
```

Are you sure, you don't already use `htmlspecialchars()`? Maybe with something like this?

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value)
}
```

I am 99,99 % sure, it has nothing to do with the database. If you would do `var_dump($comment)` instead of inserting to a database, it would be the same.