# HTML sanitizing for my tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, sanitize

I already have read a question about this here ... 
Now I know, that there are many libs, which allow me to sanitize my string...

**The Problem**

I use the TinyMCE editor for every text input on my website. Users can use HTML tags like `<b>`, `<li>`, `<ol>`, `<p>` and so on.

I don't want to "allow" cross side scripting on my website, so I need a tool, which can filter the "bad" tags :)

I want to use it like `$string = sanitize($string)`. It doesn't have to be exactly like this, but it should be easy to use ^^

I already read about such tools, but I'm not sure which one is the best ...

Suggestions would be great :)

Comment: why don't you just set your verify_html to true in tinymce? http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html

Comment: or you could use the set content method http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent

Comment: is this secure ? I mean the thing is, that jquery isnt server side ?

Comment: i think it is secure yes. its tinymce verified. but you should read this guy's solution https://www.leighton.com/blog/stop-tinymce-in-wordpress-3-x-messing-up-your-html-code

Comment: I use it raw / without wordpress ... second i want to prevent adding custom html tags like <script> , ...

Comment: yeah i thought that i was looking at the php option it can be added into any site but if you'd rather not use script tags well use one of the other 2 options ... defo both look good but i think to get the best out of verify you have to initialise it on setup

Comment: Of course it's not secure, purely client-side validation is never secure.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this check on the server side. It looks like your's is PHP (or Perl?). See this: [Sanitizing HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512712/sanitizing-html-input)