# Wordpress REST API v2 - PHP - Sanitize JSON response

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, api

I'm using the REST API v2 from Wordpress, and the response is including `<p>` tags along with HTML codes (e.g.: `&#8211`) in the content and title fields. I'd like to utilize PHP's sanitize function to get rid of the HTML. I think the file I need to touch is `/wp-includes/rest-api.php` but I'm not sure where or which function to add. Maybe `sanitize_text_field`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sanitizing HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512712/sanitizing-html-input)